# SQL Search Query for Multiple Where Clauses e.g. Firstname AND Surname

Tags: sql, t-sql, search

I have a SQL Search Query which works if I search on the First Name or the Surname:

```
SELECT     MemberID, FirstName, Surname, Title + ' ' + FirstName + ' ' + Surname AS FullName
FROM         Members
WHERE FirstName + Surname LIKE N'%' + 'Smith' + '%'
ORDER BY FullName
```

If I search for *John* I see all *John's* if I search for *Smith* I see all *Smith's* What I would like is to search for *John Smith* and see all *John Smith's*. Thanks

**UPDATE:**
I should have made my original post clearer. I am using vb.net and when the user enters a search term into a text box the actual query that is run is as follows:

```
SELECT     MemberID, FirstName, Surname, Title + ' ' + FirstName + ' ' + Surname AS FullName
FROM         Members
WHERE FirstName + Surname LIKE N'%' + @SearchTerm + '%'
ORDER BY FullName
```

I want the user to be able to type: *John S* and see all users called John with a Surname of S.

Comment: Seems like a nested select query. You can search/select for john first in your where statement and your outer select can search for the last name, Smith. You couldn't do a WHERE firstname = blah AND surname = blah?

Comment: I'm fairly new to SQL, could you perhaps provide an example?

Comment: So let me get this right - you have a vb.net string that you want to use to search two columns in your database? For example - I could enter "Joe Bloggs" and you would want to search for "Joe" and "Bloggs" in firstname and surname respectivly?

Comment: One thing. You need to sanitize the user input before inserting it into a SQL string. Else you have bugs and/or sql injection vulnerabilities.

Comment: I use Parameters which negates any SQL injection attacks, and for belt & braces I trim/Replace the String for any bad characters

Comment: @James - can you do: WHERE fullName like '%' + @SearchTerm +'%'

Obviously you have to check that the @searchTerm text is SQL safe before doing this - research SQL Injection attacks for some poitners

Comment: @james actually scrap that - aliases dont work in WHERE clauses.

Comment: @Andy - Yeah just figured that out after trying your last comment. Basically if the user types: *J S* as the search term I would like it to return all members with a first name of *J* and Surname of *S* - if that makes sense?

Comment: @JohnFX - it works perfectly if I search for *John* or for *Smith* not if I search for *John Smith*

Comment: @James yep it does, its not easy to do the way you want.
You could assume that you are always going to have input in the form "firstname lastname" and tokenize your output before sending to your parametised query. e.g. "Joe Bloggs" becomes vFname='Joe' and vLname='Bloggs', then your SQL is very much like my answer below - with an AND. 
Of course that doesn't allow for "three word names" or where the user only enters one word, you would have to use logic to choose to search firstname, lastname or both in this situation. The only alternative would be to concatenate the data into one column?

Comment: @Andy - With your concatenation suggestion - Do you mean create a new column called FullName and populate Mr John Smith on initial insertion, then search on that field?

Comment: well that would be one way of doing it - but thats holding more data than you need to. However if you did this you could then use full text search and start looking at ordering by relevance and so on.
You could also achieve it using temporary tables / views. For example, the view would be a select on your user table, with an extra column for the concatenated name. You could then search on the "true" fullName, which gets around the alias problem

Comment: CREATE view Member_view
AS
(SELECT     MemberID, FirstName, Surname, Title + ' ' + FirstName + ' ' + Surname AS FullName
FROM         Members);

Comment: @Andy - That's about as close as I am going to get - Thanks for your help!

Comment: No problem - its such a simple problem, with no simple solutions unfortunately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT     MemberID, FirstName, Surname, Title + ' ' + FirstName + ' ' + Surname AS FullName
FROM         Members
WHERE FirstName LIKE '%john%'
AND Surname LIKE '%smith%'
ORDER BY FullName;
```

Comment: ahh sorry I missed the tSQL tag, i had my Oracle hat on ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Based on the caveats and conditions in your comments on other questions, your best bet is going to be have two search boxes (firstname and surname) and build a query that looks something like this.

```
SELECT   MemberID, FirstName, Surname, Title + ' ' + FirstName + ' ' + Surname AS FullName
FROM         Members
WHERE FirstName like N'%' + @SearchFirst + '%' AND
      Surname LIKE N'%' + @SearchSurname + '%'
ORDER BY FullName
```

Alternatively you could try to manually parse a single search box into first and last name before inserting the values into your query. But parsing names is a very dicey affair not entered into lightly.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT     MemberID, FirstName, Surname, Title + ' ' + FirstName + ' ' + Surname AS FullName
FROM         Members
WHERE FirstName + Surname LIKE N'%' + 'Smith' + '%'
ORDER BY FullName
```

Okie, I'mma try to take a crack at this. Assuming that you want to search for last and first name.

```
SELECT     MemberID, FirstName, Surname, Title + ' ' + FirstName + ' ' + Surname AS FullName
FROM         Members
WHERE FirstName='John' AND Surname='Smith'
ORDER BY FullName
```

Would this work?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT     MemberID, FirstName, Surname, Title + ' ' + FirstName + ' ' + Surname AS FullName
FROM         Members
WHERE FirstName + ' ' + Surname LIKE N'%' + SearchTerm + '%'
ORDER BY FirstName
```

Here SearchTerm could be any
John Smith,
Or
John S,
Or
John,
Or simply
J

Comment: @ Waqas Raja - That's almost right, but if the user types *Joh S* by accident they get no results.

Comment: hmm you need to split the user input by space bar character and then you need where FirstName like N'%' + firstTerm + '%' and LastName like N'%' + lastTerm + '%'

Comment: @James - You really have to decide what your question is. You are changing the requirements every time someone answers.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have data like this:

```
     Firstname              |  Lastname
     John Stewart           |  Mill
```

your query above with Searchterm = '%John M%' will find all the Johns whose surname begins with M, provided that you concatenate a space:

```
           where firstname + ' ' + lastname like '%John S%'
```

However you won't get great performance with CONTAINS-SUBSTRING type queries (i.e. wildcard on either side of the search term). Starts-with queries can make use of an index, so it would better to write:

```
     where firstname = 'John'    -- can use an index on firstname column
     and lastname like 'S%'      -- can use an index on lastname column
```